# How to multiply two dataframes of different shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

the first datframe `df1` looks like this:

```
    variable            value
0   plastic             5774
2   glass               42
4   ferrous metal       642
6   non-ferrous metal   14000
8   paper               4000
```

Here is the head of the second dataframe `df2`:

```
waste_type           total_waste_recycled_tonne   year   energy_saved
non-ferrous metal    160400.0                     2015    NaN
glass                14600.0                      2015    NaN
ferrous metal        15200                        2015    NaN
plastic              766800                       2015    NaN
```

I want to update the `energy_saved` in the second dataframe `df2` such that I multiply the `total_waste_recycled_tonne` variable in df2 by the variable in df1 into the `energy_saved` column in df2.

For example:

For plastic: 5774 will be multipled with every `waste_type` `platic` with the `total_waste_recycled_tonne` variable in df2

ie:
`energy_saved` = 5774 * 766800

Here is what I tried:

```
df2["energy_saved"] = df1[df1["variable"]=="plastic"]["value"].values[0] * df2["total_waste_recycled_tonne"][df2["waste_type"]=="plastic"]
```

However the problem was that when I do others, the rest changes back to `NaN`. I need a better approach to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `merge()` and pass `how='right'`:

```
df=df1[['variable','value']].merge(df2[['waste_type','total_waste_recycled_tonne']],left_on='variable',right_on='waste_type',how='right')
```

Finally:

```
df2["energy_saved"]=df['value'].mul(df['total_waste_recycled_tonne'])
```

Output of `df2`:

```
    waste_type          total_waste_recycled_tonne  year    energy_saved
0   non-ferrous metal   160400.0                    2015    2.245600e+09
1   glass               14600.0                     2015    6.132000e+05
2   ferrous metal       15200.0                     2015    9.758400e+06
3   plastic             766800.0                    2015    4.427503e+09
4   plastic             762700.0                    2015    4.403830e+09
```

Comment: hey updated answer...I think that you need right merge so passed `how='right'` parameter in merge method

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
df2['energy_saved'] = (df2['waste_type'].map(df1.set_index('variable')['value'])
                          .mul(df2['total_waste_recycled_tonne']
                      )
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) option:

```
df2['energy_saved'] = (
        df1.set_index('variable').reindex(df2['waste_type'])['value'] *
        df2.set_index('waste_type')['total_waste_recycled_tonne']
).values
```

`df2`:

```
          waste_type  total_waste_recycled_tonne  year  energy_saved
0  non-ferrous metal                    160400.0  2015  2.245600e+09
1              glass                     14600.0  2015  6.132000e+05
2      ferrous metal                     15200.0  2015  9.758400e+06
3            plastic                    766800.0  2015  4.427503e+09
4            plastic                    762700.0  2015  4.403830e+09
```